# MS ADFS -ssolifetime for refresh token

Tags: azure-active-directory, dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics, adfs, adfs2.0

AD-FS define refresh token life time to be equal to SSO lifetime. What would be the new refresh token life time, if we replace the refresh token with the newly acquired refresh token which we get in access token call.

For eg :  If my ssolifetime is 720 mins(8 hrs) and after 6 hrs i make a call to get new access token which will also return a new refresh token. What would be the ssolifetime for this new refresh token. Is it 2 hrs(as 6 hrs is already elapsed) or it works in sliding manner and new life time for this newly acquired refresh token would be another 8 hrs starting from 6th hr.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, in ADFS, if you are an unregistered device, and you don't use Keep me signed in option when signing in, then the Refresh token is = to the sso, which by default is 8 hours. 
the way I understand it is you do NOT get a new refresh token in this scenario. so if you renew your token before the 8 refresh token expires, I would think your access token is good for another 8 hours, but your refresh token is no good anymore, so next time you try to get a new token it will fail.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/identity/ad-fs/operations/ad-fs-single-sign-on-settings#enable-psso-for-office-365-users-to-access-sharepoint-online

there's also Persistent SSO, for authenticated devices, and keep me signed in for unauthenticated devices, they all behave differently. but there is no indication that a unauthenticated device without "keepmesignedin" would ever get a new refresh token in adfs.

> Session SSO cookies are written for the authenticated user which eliminates further prompts when the user switches applications during a particular session. However, if a particular session ends, the user will be prompted for their credentials again.
>
> With KMSI disabled, the default single sign-on period is 8 hours. This
>   can be configured using the property SsoLifetime. The property is
>   measured in minutes, so its default value is 480.

I hope this helps a bit.

Comment: Kinda not, my question remains answered here, what is the purpose of new refresh token which i receive while getting access token. Does this new refresh token expiration timer start from zero?

Comment: if you are using an unauthenticated/unregistered device, you should not be getting a new refresh token when you ask for a new access token.